# Ignore certain area(roi) in an image while processing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I'm a fresher to Matlab. I'm working on
vision.CascadeObjectDetector on Mat-lab and is used
twice to find-out two different objects(separately
trained), say E and K from a video. bbox and bbox2
are respective ROIs. part of code in while loop is given below:

```
videoFrame=step(videoFileReader);
bbox=step(letterDetector_E,videoFrame);
bbox2=step(letterDetector_K,videoFrame);
C = vertcat(bbox,bbox2);
videoOut=insertObjectAnnotation(videoFrame, 'rectangle', C, 'E&K');
step(videoPlayer, videoOut);
```

I want to ignore the area denoted by bbox while finding out bbox2. That is, no two object should be find out from same part of image(obviously there are similiarities in both type of objects). So I wish to mask or ignore bbox area of videoFrame while 
bbox2 is assigned with step(letterDetector_K, videoFrame)
is executing. Format of bbox is [xUpperLeft, yUpperLeft, width,
height]. 
How can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty easy to do.  Once you detect the first shape, use the bounding box detected for the first object `E`, then insert a filled rectangle in that spot using [`insertShape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html).  Make sure you set the `Opacity` to 1.0 so that it doesn't mix any pixels from the background into this rectangle, and choose a colour of the filled rectangle that is completely different from the object you're trying to detect.  Perhaps choose black.  Also, I would recommend you turn off anti-aliasing when drawing the rectangle, because it actually takes more time to draw a shape with this turned on.  Anti-aliasing essentially smoothes edges for any shapes.  Because you don't want to include information with this region, there's really no need for anti-aliasing and so set this to `false`.  This is done with the `SmoothEdges` option.

Once you're finished filling the shape in, use this modified frame and detect the next object `K`.  As such, you only need one more line of code, so do this:

```
videoFrame=step(videoFileReader);    
bbox=step(letterDetector_E,videoFrame);

%// NEW - Insert filled rectangle
videoFrame = insertShape(videoFrame, 'FilledRectangle', bbox, ...
                         'Opacity', 1.0, 'Color', 'black', ...
                         'SmoothEdges', false);

%// Now detect next shape on modified frame
bbox2=step(letterDetector_K,videoFrame);

C = vertcat(bbox,bbox2);
videoOut=insertObjectAnnotation(videoFrame, 'rectangle', C, 'E&K');
step(videoPlayer, videoOut);
```

How `insertShape` works is that it takes in an image (`videoFrame` in your case), then you specify the `FilledRectangle` flag and the bounding box location, which precisely coincides with a 4 element array in the way you described, which is the `x` and `y` of top-left corner, followed by width and height of the rectangle.  We will place a filled in rectangle at this location.  We then specify further options for the rectangle before drawing it, such as setting the opacity to 1.0, the colour to black and anti-aliasing turned off.  We output the modified frame with this rectangle inserted, where I will mutate `videoFrame` so that there is minimal editing required for your code.  You would then use `videoFrame` to detect the next shape.

Comment: Plz... One more help... I was trying to find out certain letters by object detection. Now my problem is, I have to Extract consecutive letters of the word. Actually, it incorrectly find some false positives. I want to avoid it. The actual letters are obviously nearby consecutively (in x axis) placed. Is there any way to do that?